# getResources to build top level menu

Tags: modx-revolution

I am trying to use `getResources` to build the main navigation for my site. How do I tell `getResources` to start at the current context and look at all resources immediately under the current context?

I see I can specify the following parameters;

1. parents
2. resources

I have set parents to `0` and that doesn't work.  I don't know the resource `id` for the context so I cannot specify it for the resources parameter.

Can't I do what I want with `getResources`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build navigation on http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Wayfinder he has a parameters to work with contexts.

Comment: +1 Wayfinder is specifically designed for building site navigation

Comment: It's not an answer for that question. You should mention about Wayfinder as suggestion.

Comment: @jacqbus better first learn something about modx berfore advising anything.

Comment: @Vasis I know modx like very well and i know that wasn't an answer for given question. For example i need to build menu and i HAVE TO use getResources (because, for example, need to use getPage also). I found that page WITHOUT proper answer, just with suggestion "use Wayfinder" so IMO this shouldn't be marked as right answer. Anyway I posted proper answer below.

Answer (score 0):

use &context, from the docs at rtfm.modx.com "Which Context should be searched in. Defaults to the current Context."

so your minimum getResources call would probably looks something like:

```
[[getResources? &parents=0 &tpl=menuTpl ]]
```

You don't have to specify the context, also, getResources is very server resource intensive, unless you have a specific reason not to, use wayfinder as Vasis suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I just came up with this, **tested and working on Revo 2.2.10**.

The way you tell getResources to start at the current context is setting the parent to the ID of the current document.

This would go in your template:

```
<ul>
    [[getResources? &parents=`0` &depth=`0` &limit=`0` &sortby=`menuindex` &sortdir=`ASC` &tpl=`tpl_Navigation`]]
</ul>
```

And then in the Chunk used as a template for getResources (tpl_Navigation):

```
<li>
    <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+menutitle:default=`[[+pagetitle]]`]]</a>

   [[getResources? &parents=`[[+id]]` &depth=`0` &totalVar=`numChildren[[+id]]` &limit=`0` &tpl=`tpl_Navigation` &sortby=`menuindex` &sortdir=`ASC` &toPlaceholder=`children[[+id]]`]]

   [[+numChildren[[+id]]:gt=`0`:then=`<ul>[[+children[[+id]]]]</ul>`:else=``]]
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getResource to generate menu from the top of current context, you need to add `` &depth=`0` &context=`[[*context_key]]` `` parameters as well.

But for simple menu generation in modx i suggest You to use [Wayfinder](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/wayfinder) plugin insted of getResource.